# Angular 6: How to write jasmine test spec for a mat-dialog

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular-unit-test

I trying to write a test spec for mat-dialog, but i could not be success, the problem is that it is called by a function. How to do that? Thanks for your help.
Here is my code

```js
closeDialogCancelButton() {
    if (this.editFormData.dirty) {
      let dialogRef = this.dialogCancel.open(DialogCancel,
        {
          width: '250px',
          disableClose: true,
          data:
          {
            id: '1'
          }
        });
      dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
        if (result)
          this.dialog.close();
      });
    } else
      this.dialog.close();
  }
```

Comment: Can you add all the component code?

Comment: i cant provide all component code, but i think this is enough for creating specs in jasmine.

Comment: i tried for many times, but some errors happening bcoz of its pointing to other components.

Comment: what is `this.dialogCancel` is it a service?

Comment: its just an object of matdialog

Comment: Are you sure that you are not injecting `dialogCancel` to the component constructor?

Answer (score 3):

I've solved the same by mocking `MatDialog`. i.e:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';

export class MatDialogMock {
    open() {
        return {
            afterClosed: () => of({ name: 'some object' })
        };
    }
}
```

Then provide this mock in your TestBed config.

`providers: [{provide: MatDialog, useClass: MatDialogMock}]`

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Danilo's answer, and with Angular 7 you can test the `matDialog` similarly to the below.

With the method to test being:

```
openExport() {
    const dialogRef = this.matDialog.open(ExportComponent, {
        data: {}
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
        if (result !== 'cancel') {
            this.export(result);
        }
    });
}
```

And with my `mat-dialog-close` action defined as such:

```
<div mat-dialog-actions>
    <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="'cancel'">Cancel</button>
    ...
</div>
```

You can use the below tests:

```
describe('openExport', () => {
  const testCases = [
    {
      returnValue: 'Successful output from dialog',
      isSuccess: true
    },
    {
      returnValue: 'cancel',
      isSuccess: false
    },
  ];

  testCases.forEach(testCase => {
    it(`should open the export matDialog and handle a ${testCase.isSuccess} output`, () => {
      const returnedVal = {
        afterClosed: () => of(testCase.returnValue)
      };
      spyOn(component, 'export');
      spyOn(component['matDialog'], 'open').and.returnValue(returnedVal);
      component.openExport();

      if (testCase.isSuccess) {
        expect(component.export).toHaveBeenCalled();
      } else {
        expect(component.export).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
      }

      expect(component['matDialog'].open).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
});
```

Remembering to provide your `TestBed.configureTestingModule` with the `matDialog` and `MAT_DIALOG_DATA`:

```
providers: [
  { provide: MatDialogRef, useValue: {} },
  { provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: {} }
]
```